# Camera starts on boot after L upgrade - Nexus 10

Tags: camera, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-nexus-10

I upgraded my wife's nexus 10 to L. Since then the camera app runs in foreground after every boot. (It was fine in kitkat). Why would this be? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you unlock how are you swiping?

If you swipe to the right, that will open the dialer after you input your pin.

If you swipe to the left, it will open the camera after you input your pin.

If you swipe up, it goes straight to the home screen after you input your pin.

(https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/TkooKgxhgmg)

Comment: I took some time to see how she was unlocking the device. She hadn't realised that the swipe direction had different actions.